# How to push data into array using mongoose, with schema having single only single object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning Mongoose, and got struct on pushing data into array blogs.
my schema is

```
module.exports = function(mongoose) {
var UserSchema   = new Schema({  
    count:String,
    _id : {id:false},
    blogs: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Blog' }]
},
{
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' }
});

var BlogSchema   = new Schema({ 
blogs:[{ 
    post : String,
    title: String,
    author : String,
    userId: {
        type: String,
        default: function() {
            return crypto.randomBytes(12).toString('hex');
        }
    },
    _id: {type: String, required: true}

}],


});

var models = {
  User : mongoose.model('User', UserSchema),
  Blog : mongoose.model('Blog', BlogSchema)
};

return models;
}
```

Problem is here userSchema will always have/be a single object, whcih will keep track of count of total blogs.

I know it can be done using **findOneAndUpdate** but I don't have id/object created for UserSchema.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to persist a collection that will have only one document? If you wanna get the number of blogs in the collection, you can use the `count` function.

Comment: Thanks, I will use count :)